# Verify digital signature PDF openssl_pkcs7_verify or openssl_verify

Tags: php, openssl

I'm trying verify(php 7) two digital signatures of a pdf file and I'm getting the next mistake:

```
error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
```

Have someone known the reason that?
The php code snippet:

```
$doc = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/doc.pdf';
$result = openssl_pkcs7_verify($doc, PKCS7_TEXT);
print_r(openssl_error_string()); //print of the error
var_dump($result);die; // Only test
```

Comment: php code snippet: openssl_pkcs7_verify($doc, PKCS7_TEXT); //$doc is a realpath for pdf file.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code.

Comment: I have signed this pdf file with two digital signatures using the code next:
$status = openssl_pkcs7_sign($doc, $signature, 'file://'. realpath('/home/henrique/Documentos/certificadosDigitais/UEMS_II/UEMS_II.crt'), array('file://'. realpath('/home/henrique/Documentos/certificadosDigitais/UEMS_II/UEMS_II.key'), ''), array(), PKCS7_TEXT);